# Как обработать и извлечь нужную информацию из списка веб-элементов

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как обработать список веб-элементов и извлечь нужную информацию?

На вебстранице есть некое количество элементов, в которых есть нужная информация. Я нашел элементы на странице, сделал список:

```java
package org.example.EmailCollectors.Pages;
    
import org.example.EmailCollectors.BasePages.BaseSeleniumPage;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AllVacanciesList extends BaseSeleniumPage {
    private List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"vacContainer\"]/div")
    private List<WebElement> listOfVacanciesElements;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"vacContainer\"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/a")
    private WebElement rabotaTitle;

    public AllVacanciesList() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public AnnaunsmentElem openAnaunsment() {
        for (int i = 1; i < listOfVacanciesElements.size(); i++) {
            WebElement rabotaTitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"vacContainer\"]/div[" + i + "]/div[1]/div/a"));
            rabotaTitle.click();
        }
        return new AnnaunsmentElem();
    }
}
```

Пытался через массив, но получал ошибку. Необходимо возвращаться на предыдущую страницу, чтобы обработать другой элемент, в чём и состоит проблема.

В вышеприведенном коде я нахожу все элементы на странице и сохраняю их в `listOfVacanciesElements`. В каждом элементе есть ссылка (`rabotaTitle`) на другую страницу.

Используются следующие зависимости:
`pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Selenium1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe/config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For standard jdk1.4 logging :-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-jdk14 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For slf4j-simple logging :-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```